# Antd/React: Trying to style the 'extra' parameter of the Antd Collapse Panel element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an antd panel as part of a collapse/accordion element and I'm trying to style and render an additional section of text as part of the header. I read through their docs and they allow you to add extra elements in by utilizing the `extra` property but I can't seem to style it or add conditional rendering properties. What I'm trying to achieve is to set the right side text of the header to 'show' when the accordion is closed and change it to 'hide' when the accordion is open. I also want to style the text blue. I've ventured down different approaches including the following function at the top and nothing works. With this current implementation I'm getting several errors.

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
>
> index.js:1446 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `extra` supplied to `CollapsePanel`, expected a ReactNode.
>
> index.js:1446 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

The following is my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Col, Row, Collapse } from 'antd'
import Checkbox from '../elements/Checkbox'
import icon from '../../assets/caretDown.svg'
import Button from '../elements/Button'

const { Panel } = Collapse

function showHide() {
  return Collapse.isActive ? <p>SHOW</p> : <p>HIDE</p>
}

const ConfigurationOptions = () => (
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col span={12}>
        <StyledCollapse>
          <Panel
            header="DROPDOWN EXAMPLE"
            key="1"
            showArrow={false}
            bordered={false}
            extra={showHide}
          >
            <div>
              <StyledH1>Placeholder</StyledH1>
            </div>
        </Panel>
      </StyledCollapse>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
)

const StyledH1 = styled.h1`
  font-weight: 700;
`

const StyledCollapse = styled(Collapse)`
  &&& {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
`

export default ConfigurationOptions
```

Comment: Fix your code from syntax errors beforehand

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I added the closing ```</Container>``` tag that I was missing. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collapse.Panel](https://ant.design/components/collapse/) `extra` property accepts `ReactNode` not a function, which means you need to pass a `ReactElement` to it:

```js
extra={<p>{disabled ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE'}</p>}
```

```js
function FromValidate() {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  return (
    <Flexbox>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}>
          <StyledCollapse onChange={() => setDisabled(prev => !prev)}>
            <Collapse.Panel
              header="DROPDOWN EXAMPLE"
              key="1"
              showArrow={false}
              bordered={false}
              extra={<p>{disabled ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE'}</p>}
            >
              <div>
                <StyledH1>Placeholder</StyledH1>
              </div>
            </Collapse.Panel>
          </StyledCollapse>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Flexbox>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://s093f.csb.dev/)

[image: Edit Q-56761334-Style-Collapse-Extra]

Comment: Hey! So this is almost working, the only issue I have is that because I have 3 separate Panels when I apply this logic to all 3 it effects all of them simultaneously even if there's only one panel open and the others are still collapsed. I forked your original sandbox and updated it to show what I mean here: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-56761334-style-collapse-extra-bdcbz. Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Your question is out of the scope of this one, you should ask another one (feel free to send me the link)(and accepting answer)

Comment: Answer accepted, new question is up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774261/react-react-hooks-onchange-function-to-change-text-is-changing-for-all-3-elemen